# Dynamic column in Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a website in many languages (en, fr, es), in my database I have for example a table countries with: id, name_en, name_fr and name_es as columns which contains respectively the name of country in english, french and spanish.

I'm working with mvc 3, c# and Entity framework.

I already have a function which returns the current language: GetCurrentLang() and returns string "en", "fr", or "es".

I want to order by the right column and get in my foreach the right column too.

Here is my code :

```
using (var db = new InsoutingContext())
        {
            var queryCountries = from qCountries in db.Countries.Where(r => r.Cities.Count > 0 )
                                 orderby qCountries.Name_fr
                                 select qCountries;
            foreach (var item in queryCountries)
            {
                Countries.Add(new ListItem((item.Name_fr), item.Id.ToString()));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way you've modelled it, you would need to append the ordering to the query conditionally, e.g:

```
var currentLang = GetCurrentLang();
var queryCountries = db.Countries.Where(r => r.Cities.Count > 0 );

if (currentLang == "es")
{
   queryCountries = queryCountries.OrderBy(c => c.Name_Es);
}
else if (...) // etc.
```

You aren't doing a projection, so the result of your query will be a sequence of countries which contain all of your properties anyway.

This model obviously isn't very scalable, so I would normalise your *countries* table and have a foreign key which references a *languages* or *cultures* table instead, and then use navigation properties on your entities. Then you would only be loading the countries for the current language, and you can just order them by name.

Comment: Thanx to reply, That is the thing i dont want to do, because, all my table have some thing like that, I guess i must do the same on Countries.Add(new ListItem((item.Name_fr), item.Id.ToString()));, and in every where.

When you told "Because of the way you've modelled it" can you suggest me how i must modelled it, for example in this table. I must move if I don't reply :)
Znd thanx for reply again

Comment: Yes exactly, so you would need to change your model as described. E.g. countries - Id, LanguageId, Name. languages - Id, Code. That's the simplest one-to-many relationship example.

Comment: You may want to introduce a translations table so that the same country isn't modelled as different entities just for culture differences.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't saw your suggestion in your first response, i saw code and I began to think in it, and reply.
So I will have 3 lines for every value in all my tables. 
That's sounds great, even i didn't wish to have 3 lines in tables for every country, city, and other tables.
Fortunately i just began the app so i can remodeled it.
Second question if you can : why when we delete a column in sql server and update the model edmx in VS, it won't delete the attributes in entities ?
And the last question about stackoverflow why wen we write "Hi" in the begin of question it deleted it ? Thanks :)

Comment: hi again, i reopen the topic :) I finished remodeling, but realise that i have a little problem with that. A user (Users table) have a City so Users contains CityId as a foreign key which references Cities. But in this case (remodeled db) user will have only one City and in one language. How fix that ?
I have two ideas but not really sure if they're good: 
1: create an ASS_City_User (id_user, id_city) or 
2 : add an other Id_Second in City and assign the same Id_Second to the same City in different languages. and in Users add Id_Second
WHat you think ?  :)

Comment: Well really the pattern is the same per entity - have a Users table with CityId, a Cities table which contains data common to all cultures, and then a CitiesTranslations or similar table which contains e.g. Id, CityId (foreign key to Cities), LanguageId (key to your languages/cultures table), and Name. So there would be an entry in CitiesTranslations for different city name.

Comment: Hummm! I was afraid to do that because I have a lot of tables to translate, and now i must have two tables for one, but seems to be the most elegant way as you suggested. Thanks to reply :)
I'm writing a new question in new post about checkboxes in mvc4, hope you sill there; your explanation is clear. Thanks